# View different HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to view different HTML pages based on what a user clicks. For example, I have three tabs set up as so:

```
<div class="span7" >
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" ng-click="first()" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="second()" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="third()" data-toggle="tab">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="span12" style="margin-left:0;" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

And I merely want to view a different page based off of what the individual clicks. For example, if he clicks `First`, he will see First's html page where `source.sourceObject` in the code below denotes which html page to view. It is written like so:

```
<div class="span5">
    <div class="edus-activity-container">
        <div ng-show="sourceViewState.selected" class="edus-admin-activities-grid" />
    </div>
        <div ng-include="'/partials/' + source.sourceObject + '.html'"/>
</div>
```

where in my javascript file, source.sourceObject is defined based off of if I click the `First`, `Second` or `Third` tab. However, my implementation is not working. I made sure I had no typos in the spelling of my files in source.sourceObject. Any ideas on how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
var pages = { 'one': 'partials/one.html', 'two':'partials/two.html' }
$scope.currentPage = pages['one'] ; //This is required if you want a default page 

$scope.first = function(){ $scope.currentPage = pages['one']; }
$scope.two = function(){ $scope.currentPage = pages['two']; }
```

In your template/HTML

```
<div ng-include="currentPage"/>
```